# incompatible pointer types assigning to "uiviewcontroller<hellodelegate>" from uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

home.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIViewController<hellodelegate> *contentController;
```

Home.m

```
UINavigationController  *cntrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondview];
      cntrl.view.frame = self.contentInView.bounds;
        cntrl.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        [self.contentInView addSubview:cntrl.view];
        self.contentController =cntrl;
```

i am getting warning self.contentController=cntrl line.

suggest me. how to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a UINavigationController to UIViewController which gives you the warning.
Change the following code in the .h file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController <hellodelegate> *contentController;
```

Comment: He'll still get the warning. `UINavigationController` certainly doesn't implement `hellodelegate`

Comment: same warning i got it. contentcontroller is viewcontroller . it is not navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

It's because the compiler knows that `UINavigationController` doesn't implement your `hellowdelegate` protocol. You told the compiler that whatever gets assigned to `contentController` must be at least a `UIViewController` and must implement `hellodelegate`. The `UINavigationController` satisfies the first but not the second, so the compiler is warning you that something may be wrong (what you told it to do and what you told it that it needs are now different, so you need to resolve the conflict here).

Comment: i want navigate from this view to another view by navigation controller only. how can solve this issue

Comment: Remove the `hellodelegate` protocol requirement from the property definition. Make it just `@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* contentController`

Comment: i did  like this. but same line same warning

Comment: @Ram you can't be getting the same warning, it must be somewhere else. If you changed the property to a simple navigation controller, and you're assigning a navigation controller, there will be no warning. Even if you left the property a view controller, you can always assign more specific to less specific without warning. The warning comes from your protocol specification (less specific to more specific assignment). Did you remove the `hellodelegate` protocol from the property definition?

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationController` doesn't implement `<hellodelegate>` protocol, you can make subclass of `MyController : UINavigationController <hellodelegate>` , or you can add Category to `UINavigationController` that implement `<hellodelegate>` if it will be helpful.